# How can I pass focus to ref on other elements blur in TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a form with a field and a button, I would like to make the button stand out on input's blur so I have placed a ref on a button

```
const btnRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

and written function

```
  const passFocus = () => {
    btnRef.current?.focus();
  };
```

but on the button ref typescript has a problem saying

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<null>'.
  Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
    Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
      Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
Button.tsx(10, 3): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

the button itself looks like so

```
 <Button
        color={COLORS.TERTIARY}
        textColor={COLORS.FONT_COLOR}
        onPress={handleSubmit((data) => onSubmit(data))}
        ref={btnRef}
      >
        Enter
      </Button>
```

If this is of any importance this is React Native

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the first render ref is null and you add only HTMLElement for type so you should do below:

```js
const btnRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);


const passFocus = () => {
    btnRef?.current?.focus();
  };
```

and optional chaining for btnRef in passFocus